# Increasing the maximum Ajax POST size

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables, post, limit

just want to know if it is possible to increase the size limit of a POST variable used with AJAX? 
In fact, I tried to insert in Database a long html code string, but it always cropped? 
A found several solutions, but nothing seem to work ...

### Here is my Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#send_ajax').click(function() {
            var html = escape($('#html_code').val());
                
            $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "test.php",
                 data: { html_code: html },
                 success: success
            });
        
        });
});
```

It working, but when I put a large string (HTML code) inside my textarea (#html_code), the string is automatically cut inside the Database. So, I just have the half of the string.

### Here is what I tried :

**.htaccess file:**
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
LimitRequestBody 0
LimitXMLRequestBody 0

**Apache httpd.conf file:**
LimitRequestBody 0

Can you help me ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check on the max length of the field in the database. For example, if your field is set to VARCHAR(1000), it is only going to accept 1000 characters. Increase the length of the data type accordingly.

Comment: Thank you !! Effectively I was using a regular text field instead of a longtext field.. :S

Answer (score 0):

If your post results are coming through as completely empty (which wasn't the OP's problem), you may very well be running up against the PHP server limits that were self (or corporately) imposed.

The setting to increase in your php.ini file is:

```
post_max_size = 8M
```

I increased mine to 32M, restarted my server, and was able to successfully POST what I had wanted.